# C++ float into Python float wrong conversion

Tags: c++, python, swig

I'm using SWIG to wrap my C++ code into Python. But the conversion of floating point numbers is strange.
For example, if I have the function below (written in C++)

```
float foo() {
    float x=62.02;
    return x;
}
```

and executes it (after wrapping with SWIG) in Python

```
>>> import mymodule
>>> mymodule.foo()
62.02000045776367
>>>
```

it returns `62.02000045776367` instead of `62.02`.

Is there a way to tell SWIG how to make the right conversion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other than the lossless `float`->`double` conversion, there is no conversion going on.

`62.02` cannot be represented exactly as a C `float`. The moment you do `float x=62.02`, the variable will contain the value that you mention.

I highly recommend reading [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: That was a dumb question. I did not notice that I was using the wrong type. Using `double` solved everything. Thanks to all!!!

Comment: @CaioS., still read the link. This is not just a `float` vs. `double` problem, but a very fundamental aspect of many programming languages.

Answer (score 6):

This is the correct conversion, it's just that you cannot represent the decimal `62.02` precisely with a `float`, much like you cannot represent the fraction `2/3` in decimal.

You can see a little more with this short code, where you will see what C++ sees when you store `62.02` as both `float` and `double`: http://ideone.com/HvfZb

Comment: But there is a way to get the precise value in Python?

Comment: Also note that Python's float type corresponds to the double type in C++. You are seeing a difference in precision because of the conversion from float to double.

Comment: @Caio: That *is* the precise value that C has. It never has "62.02" in the first place.

Comment: @CaioS. Python did get the precise value you returned.

Comment: @casevh although even if he did use a `double`, it would still not be precisely `62.02`

Comment: @CaioS. Try printing x with many digits from C++ and you'll confirm what the others say.